# XPath for email scraping using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I need to scrape multiple contact pages for e-mail adresses in python using selenium. They are all different in their layout and site structure, so I have to come up with a very dynamic XPATH pattern for finding the adresses.

An additional obstacle is that the adresses are sometimes plain text and sometimes an `href mailto:`

The pattern I have so far kinda works:

```
email = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'@')]]").text
```

But it does not work if multiple data is stored in the same `div` 
It also returns a list of elements but I only need the email. If I use `find_element_by_xpath` there is no text at all.

An example of this would be if you tried to scrape this site: http://schandorf.at/service/kontakt/

So if you have any tips, please let me know!

Comment: Did you try beautifulsoup?

Comment: @NoSkillMan I was looking into it but I try to keep things simple and I wanted to know if I could do it using Selenium only. If that is not possible, I will use BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of your pages you can try something like this (example with the website you've posted) :

```
emailA = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='col3']//p[contains(.,'@')]").text
emailA_fix = re.search('E-Mail: (.+?)[A-Z]',value).group(1)
emailB = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'mailto:')]").get_attribute("href")

email = emailA_fix + emailB
```

`emailA` = search for email address in text format ; `email B` = search for email address in mailto format

With `emailA`, we use a regex(re.search) to extract the mail address.

Output : `post@schandorf.bgld.gv.at`

With LXML or Scrapy you could use a single XPath expression to support the multiple structures of your pages :

```
 //div[@id='col3']//text()[contains(.,'Mail')]|//a[contains(@href,"mailto:")]/@href
```